# How can I parse errors using GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

My response is:

```
{
    "data":[],
    "meta":[],
    "errors":[["invalid credentials"]]
}
```

I am not able to de-serialize it by below method:

```
Errors errors = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<Errors>(){}.getType());
```

**Errors**

```
public class Errors {
    private HashMap<String, Object> errors;

    public HashMap<String, Object> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
}
```

How to de-serialize errors correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `Errors` is not Hashmap, it is an array of arrays.
Change the class to this and see whether it works or not.

```
public class Errors {

  private List<List<String>> errors;

  public List<List<String>> getErrors() {
     return errors;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    Errors errors=new Gson().fromJson("here your error data",Errors.class);
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got   "System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException"

Comment: that time your json is wrong format check into jsonviewer website.

Answer (score 0):

You are de-serializing - not errors - but a response having these errors. There JSON presents an object say `Response` that contains `data`, `meta` & `errors`.

So you cannot not pass the JSON in your question and expect it to be de-serialized as an instance of `Errors`. Instead you need some DTO that matches to your JSON response string. It could be like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Response {
    // You can comment/remove data & meta
    // if you do not need then
    private List<?> data;
    private List<?> meta;
    private List<List<String>> errors;
}
```

De-serialize like:

```
Response res = new Gson().fromJson(YOUR_JSON, Response.class);
```

and get errors like:

```
res.getErrors();
```